# Rails - how can I create an ajax link for row highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I have a great example of instant row hilighting that I want to do:
http://www.mrc-productivity.com/techblog/?p=684

How can I create a `<a href="#" class="on">Turn on row highlights</a>` link with rails.

I have tried many combination of link_to and button_to with :remote => true but I can't get the syntax right and everything seems to end up with a regular link.

At the end of the day I am trying to turn on and off row table highlighting as in:

html:

```
<a href="#" class="on">Turn on row highlights</a>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.on").click(function(){
    $("tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("two");
    $("tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("one");
    event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("a.off").click(function(){
        $("tr:nth-child(odd)").removeClass("two");
        $("tr:nth-child(even)").removeClass("one");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a link like that with:

```
link_to('Turn on row highlights', '#', :class => 'on')
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need to use the Rails helpers at all. You can simply use that link tag directly in an erb file:

```
<a href="#" class="on">Turn on row highlights</a>
```

or for HAML:

```
%a.on{href: '#'} Turn on row highlights
```

The Rails view helper are only useful when you're linking to a Rails resource. The remote: true option is used when you want to unobtrusively access a resource with AJAX. Neither apply in your case.